# Expanding UIView from within UIToolbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a `UeIView` subclass as one of the `UIToolbar's` button items. When the user taps it, I would like it to expand out of the `UIToolbar` and display some options to the user.  THe problem is, the `UIToolbar` is not letting the `UIView` present its `subviews` outside of the `toolbar's` frame.  I have `ClipToBounds` set to NO everywhere, so that is not the problem.
Any suggestions on how to handle a situation like this?

Comment: what you want?? when user tap button at that time some UIView display to user ??

Comment: I want the UIView that is within the toolbar to be able to display subviews outside of its frame and outside of the frame of the UIToolbar too.

Answer (score 1):

take one `UIView` with name viewOption after that set frame in `viewDidLoad:` method like bellow..

```
viewOption.frame = CGRectMake(0, yourToolBar.frame.origin.y, viewOption.frame.size.height, viewOption.frame.size.height);  /// define height and width which you want here
```

then in button event write this code and your view display with animation

```
-(IBAction)yourToolBarButton_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
     viewOption.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, viewOption.frame.size.height, viewOption.frame.size.height);/// here set y as you want to display in view 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: @Cameron E add UIElement as subView in UIView and adjust frame according all subviews.